# Calculation of Fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

So I have a function $$f(t)\enspace\in\enspace L^{2}([0,1])$$ $$f(t)= \begin{cases}%
  \frac{1}{2} -t       & \text{if  $0 \leq t\leq \frac{1}{2},$}\\
  0 & \text{if  $\frac{1}{2} \lt  t\leq 1$}
 \end{cases}$$

How do I calculate the Fourier coefficients $$\left\langle{f|1} \right\rangle , \left\langle{f|A_{k} } \right\rangle , and \left\langle{f|B_{k}} \right\rangle$$

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Use the formulae for $A_k$ and $B_k$ with $\int f(t) \sin/\cos(nt) dt$ splitting the integrals over the regions where $f(t)$ is differently defined.

Comment: @martycohen Thanks. So you mean I need to use the Euler formulas i.e $$A_{k} = \frac{1}{\pi }  \int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}{f(x) \cos nx\enspace dx} $$ and $$B_{k} = \frac{1}{\pi }  \int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}{f(x) \sin nx\enspace dx} $$?

Comment: Yes, with the integrals split over the regions where the function is defined.